# AASTex package: how to unnumber equations?

Tags: equations, numbering, templates

I'm using the [AASTex package](http://aastex.aas.org/) and I've been wondering how to unnumber equations (I hate numbers in equations that you don't even cite later!). So far I've tried the usual:

- Tried to put the `\nonumber` line after the equation (inside the `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`, of course), but it doesn't work.
- Tried to do `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}`, but the package didn't recognize the command. I tried adding the `\usepackage{amsmath}` package, but this causes various features of the AASTex package to fail.

Here's a working example of my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[manuscript]{aastex}
\newcommand{\vdag}{(v)^\dagger}
\newcommand{\myemail}{myemail@myuniversity.com}

\slugcomment{This is a slug comment.}

\shorttitle{A Short title!}
\shortauthors{N\'estor}

\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,pdftitle={PDF title},pdfauthor={Nestor}}
\begin{document}

\title{This is a glorious title that appears up.}

\author{N\'estor\altaffilmark{1}}
\affil{My department, my university}
\email{myemail@myuniversity.com}
\altaffiltext{1}{My affiliation.}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\section{Introduction}
Let's start with Einstein's equation:
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2. \nonumber
\end{equation}
Easy, right?
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read on page 5 of the given [documentation](http://aastex.aas.org/aasguide.pdf) you can use `\nonumber` only in the environment `eqnarray` (but `eqnarray` should no longer be used!). Add this to your MWE:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
 E=mc^2.  \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: The `aastex` class defines its own `eqnarray` so I don't know if the standard "`eqnarray` should no longer be used" advise applies here.

Comment: Ugh I don't know which to accept! The two answers are great! I think I'll accept this one, because it uses "internal" definitions of aastex (plus the reference to the documentation). Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\[...\]`:

```
\documentclass[manuscript]{aastex}
\begin{document}
Let's start with Einstein's equation:
\[
E=mc^2.
\]
Easy, right?
\end{document}
```

[image]